# MobileFirst8.0 - push token refresh

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

Suppose I have an Android device Which is successfully registered for PushNotifications using MobileFrist SDK (version 8.0).
Say-After 6 months -GCM initiates token refresh!. Will SDK be able to auto sync the push token or do we need to handle this manually?

What is the case with IOS/APNS?

Could you explain the process of token refresh and synchronization ??

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like a very precise question about IBM product. You should probably ask IBM directly about it.

Comment: Thank you Mick! Yes I am following with prodct team as well. 
Reaching out to people here to know whether anyone has come through this!

Answer (score 0):

The registerDevice API (and the sendDeviceToken API incase of iOS) of MFP Push (available in both the Android and iOS SDKs) registers the device if one is not yet or updates the device if the device token is refreshed / changed. A call to this API from the Android / iOS client application when the app is started will obtain the token for the device from APNS/GCM servers and ensures the registration on the server to be refreshed with right token whenever it changes.

For more info:
http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/android/
http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/ios/

Comment: Srinu- Thank you for reply
I somewhere had a glitch that - calling register API multiple times would lead to issues (cronologincal registration , loss of earlier subscriptions if the device is already Registerd & subscribed to any tags. )
After testing the PUSH registerAPI , I could notice 'calling registerAPI multiple times dosen't hampper/overwrite the existing subscriptions if any.' - Correct me if I am worng here!

Comment: You're right. Calling register API multiple times will not modify the existing subscriptions of the device in any manner. Its only the device registration that is updated on the server - if the token from GCM / APNS has changed.